# C# ServiceHost seemingly ignores connections from host in VM

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I've implemented a very basic service from a WSDL, I'm serving it using a `ServiceHost` object and it seems to work locally. The code I'm using to *serve the service* is this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Uri httpUri = new Uri("http://192.168.18.1:8080/");

        using (ServiceHost hService = new ServiceHost(typeof(TritonClientClient), httpUri))
        {
            // hService.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITritonClient), new BasicHttpBinding(), "http://localhost:8000/BasicService");                

            hService.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Listening. Press any key to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Closing...");

            hService.Close();
        }
    }
```

It seems to work locally, because I can browse to `http://192.168.18.1:8080/?wsdl` and I get the service description file.

**The problem** is that I need to access this service from a virtual machine (using VMware). This machine is configured to have a "host-only" network adapter, and I can ping the host from the guest and viceversa. However, I cannot access the service from the browser as I can do from the host directly.

Using Wireshark in the host I can see the guest trying to start the TCP handshake, but noone answering:

[image: Wireshark capture]

For the record, the host's IP is 192.168.18.1 and the guest's IP is 192.168.18.128. Is there anything I have to do in the `ServiceHost` so it answers the request from the VM?

Comment: Did you open this port in the Windows Firewall? Testing locally means the traffic comes from a trusted source. Testing from a VM means it does not. Hence the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your firewall settings do not block port 8080 on host machine.

Comment: It was just that. I had disabled the firewall for private networks, but looks like Windows thinks a 192.168.x.x network is a public network. Go home Windows, you're drunk.